# Fallo postgreSQL generando un trigger sencillo de borrado

Tags: postgresql

Intento crear este trigger en PostgreSQL y me da error en INSERT
no entiendo por qué:

```
CREATE TRIGGER borrar_programador
AFTER DELETE ON programadores 
FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO uso(descripcion) VALUES(OLD.nombre);
```

Comment: Saludos Javier, ¿qué dice el error? Por otro lado, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedo imaginar el error que te retorna(pero te recomiendo ser más descriptivo), pues no estás definiendo el trigger como se debe. En PostgreSQL el trigger lleva dos componentes, el trigger en si y la función trigger que es la hace la actividad que requires, te recomiendo echarle un ojo  a la [documentación al repecto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html), tu caso pudiera quedar como algo asi:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funcion_trg_borrar_programador() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$
    BEGIN
   INSERT INTO uso(descripcion) VALUES(OLD.nombre);
        RETURN NULL; 
    END;
$$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER borrar_programador
AFTER DELETE ON programadores 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE  FUNCTION funcion_trg_borrar_programador();
```